# Converting binary returned from a database to a readable pdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, binary

I have a storedp procedure that returns an array containing the binary for a PDF. I am trying to get the browser to infer the binary as the pdf without corrupting it so it can be downloaded. At the minute the following code simply returns a pdf to the browser that gets downloaded but cannot be opened as it is corrupted in some manner. Am I missing something/need to change something?

```
header ("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=apdf.pdf");
echo $return['Standard_BIN'];
```

Help much appreciated, if you need more info I will update super quick

Comment: Remove newlines and trailing spaces from your header parameters.

Comment: Also header types are case sensitive, so you should change `Content-disposition` to `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: ok, I have made those changes and still get a "this file may be damaged" error when trying to open. have updated the question too